# Why are my cookies not set on mobile devices PHP?

Tags: php

Hi i am student and i was working on my class project i ran into a particular problem, when i try to set cookies they work on the laptop but wwhen i use the phone and open the site and sign in then add something to cart after like an hour or so and i come back the site refreshes and everything is gone, the item i added to cart and the user account which is not the case on laptop browser. can you help me identify where i went wrong as i am still new to code thank you

i tried this

```
<?php
require "./resources/connection.php";
     $_COOKIE['userID'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['Unique_ID'])) {
    header("location: signup.php");
}



if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    setcookie("cart", serialize($_SESSION['cart']), time() + strtotime('+5 months'), '/'); // 30 days
    $_COOKIE['cart'];
}
```

and a few other alterations but it all doesnt work on mobile. what happens is that when someone creates an account, a unique id is set for them and stored in the database and also set in the session so that it can be used on the different pages.

Comment: `$_COOKIE['userID'];` doesn't actually do anything, so what is the point of having that in there? Same for `$_COOKIE['cart'];`. And where is your `session_start` call? And why are you even storing your cart data into a separate cookie - when you are already using a session?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why it wasn’t working I was just trying to see if it would work.. and the session is started on the file where the processes of the cart page are happening.. I moved it around to see if it would work but all the same

Comment: @CBroe to restore the cart when the session expires

Comment: _"and the session is started on the file where the processes of the cart page are happening"_ - you need to call it on _every_ page that is supposed to use the session.

Comment: I did this and I got a message saying that I can’t use it twice so I removed it on the cart page and put it directly on the processes page but it didn’t seem to work.